# Huawei/honor devices & SQLiteBlobTooBigException

Tags: android, exception, android-sqlite, huawei-mobile-services

I have got SQLiteBlobTooBigException on **huawei/honor Android 9.0** devices **only**. 
For 5k active installs.
What the matter?

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableName;
    if(!db.isOpen()){db=this.getWritableDatabase();}
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    i = cursor.getCount();
```

Other devices run well.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXcIg.png)

Comment: When dealing with databases, BLOBS are NEVER the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, the Blob (byte[]) is too large to fit into a Cursor window (4MB). A cursor window being a buffer for the rows.

Blobs are not recommend because it Blob can be stored that are larger than size that can be retrieved using the SDK's SQLite API. That is there is no buffer as such when inserting a row, so the size restriction doesn't apply.

The resolution is to save the byte[] in a file and to then save the path to the file in the database.

- Although there can be some speed improvements by saving smaller byte[]'s saving smaller byte[]'s but larger say (100k+) byte[]'s as the path to a file. [35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html). An example of such splitting can be found in the answer at [Guide to use a large sqlite propulated database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633055/guide-to-use-a-large-sqlite-propulated-database/51633408#51633408)

Comment: **Other devices run well. Why?**

Comment: @ally I don't know why but they are obviously different in some way resulting in either larger Blobs or that somehow they reduce the Cursor Window size. I believe the former is the more likely. If you apply the suggested resolution then why becomes irrelevant.

Comment: 1. Your way requires additional permission for app.
2. Here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726838](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726838/getting-random-android-database-sqlite-sqliteblobtoobigexception) is similar , but there is not Byte[].
3. Looks like battle Google vs Huawei